# python print error, math incorrect (1/10=0)

Tags: python

when I startup python, I don't import anything and I just enter `1/10`, it returns `0`. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: integer division.  Convert to float: `1/10.`

Comment: Which Python? My Python 3.5.1 is showing `0.1`.

Comment: use python 3, not python 2

Comment: You are exactly right. Making it a float fixed it. I thought it did that automatically. Also I noticed I was using 2.7 instead of 3.5. oos! I did not know this was different in 2.7.